# Cannot save php datetime in database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to save a datetime from PHP into my database, but I cannot. The datetime value in the database is always set as `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$dt = $today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET  post_date = $dt, post_date_gmt = $dt WHERE ID = $id";
```

Comment: Please use the search. [Any of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bmysql%5D+0000-00-00+00%3A00%3A00) would have helped

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try put quotation marks:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$dt = $today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET  post_date = '$dt', post_date_gmt = '$dt' WHERE ID = $id";
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply, datetime is string, not integer.

```
$today = new DateTime();
$dt = $today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET  post_date = '$dt', post_date_gmt = $dt WHERE ID = $id";
```

will be works better:)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use,

```
$dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:S");
$sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET  post_date = '$dt', post_date_gmt = '$dt' WHERE ID = $id";
```

Comment: This wouldn't help with the real issue here. You could have posted this as a comment instead. (Although it might be preferred to actually use the object-oriented approach here)

Comment: This doesn't address the original issue. And quotes don't make a difference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using date time from PHP you should use mysql inbuit now() function, no need to write extra line of code in php.

```
    $sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET  post_date = now(), post_date_gmt = now() WHERE ID = $id";
```

n you can alos set Now() in your table field so you dont need to set as query , when record will insert to update it will automatically set the current date time.

```
    CREATE TABLE tablename
    (
        fiedlId int NOT NULL,
        fieldName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        fieldDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
        PRIMARY KEY (fiedlId)
    )
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use timestamp function of mysql
**for new table**

```
$sql = CREATE TABLE newtb (current_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
or 
$sql = CREATE TABLE newtb (current_time DATETIME DEFAULT NOW());
```

**to modify Table**

```
$sql = CREATE TABLE newtb MODIFY current_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
or 
$sql = CREATE TABLE newtb MODIFY current_time DATETIME DEFAULT NOE();
```